# What approach should I take to continuously skip to a function with conditions and no loops?

Tags: javascript, html, function

//Skip to 3rd paragraph for main point.

First I want to mention I am a beginner to programming. I have decided to start editing before I can create from scratch. So I found a script that can be used within an Internet Browser's Console (The inspect element thing) to perform many tasks. So at first the script was only the size of a paragraph but over the course of few days I have been adding and editing it (which I find really fun) to create a more custom script. I want to get to the point but without context it may be difficult to help me.

So basically the script I have come up with uses alot of "Functions" I am not 100% what anything is even after studying but I know enough about what they do. So I use the functions to define conditions and to perform different tasks. I keep many functions to keep everything organized and to find mistakes. However; the problem I am having now is the script is not working properly and I cant find my mistake.

**MAIN POINT**

I have many functions going down in order but I want the script to go back up to the first function after certain conditions occur. I want to do this without using loops if possible. The way I do it is by calling the function like 
"NameOfFunction"();

Here is some of my code:

```
function roll() {
        if (Dloss === false) {
            if (loop === true) {
                tbBet.value = start;
                btRoll.click();
                refreshIntervalId = setInterval(roll2, delay);
            }
        }
        if (Dloss === true) {
            if (loop === true) {
                tbBet.value = start;
                btRoll.click();
                refreshIntervalId = setInterval(decision, delay);
            }
        }
    }
    function decision() {
        if (Dloss === true) {
            var thestring = document.getElementById('roll').value;
            var thenumber = retnum(thestring);
            if (thenumber < rollUnder) {
                start = (start * remain).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (thenumber > rollUnder) {
                start = (start * MultLoss).toFixed(2);
                if (start > maxBetValue) {
                    loop = false;
                }
                btRoll.click();
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                roll();
            }
            btRoll.click();
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            roll3();
        }
    }
```

So you can see where I have roll(); within an if statement. I want it to loop back up to the start but it doesnt seem to work. I am sorry if this is something that is obvious. I am learning and after struggling for a while I have decided to post my question here. Thanks in advance for anyhelp.

---------Edit 1-----------
So what I want to do is call the function roll() over here:

```
                     btRoll.click();
                    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                    roll();
```

So am I calling this correctly as from what I have researched this is the only way? Should I post the whole script here? (BTW sorry I am new to the site aswell still learning how to use)

Comment: what does "it doesn't seem to work" even mean? clearly if it worked, you wouldn't be asking a question - what do you observe? what behavior do you expect instead? try adding some `console.log` statements to "debug" what is happening in your code (debugger statement is a bit difficult with code being called on an interval, so I would start by tracing the execution of your code using console.logs)

Comment: Welcome to programming and I enjoy your candour! I agree with Jaromanda that we need more details to be able to help you. One thing I can say is that within your code you call two functions: roll2() and roll3() which are not defined in the code you've shared with us. One thing I should point out: functions are "defined", and then "called" elsewhere. The order in which they are defined doesn't necessarily reflect the order in which they are called.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: By "it doesnt seem to work" I mean after the conditions are applied the code doesnt go back to the first function. The behaviour I expect is after the if statement is applied I want the code to be "read" from the beginning, I dont want it to continue from its current "reading spot" (Sorry i dont know term). Also I am not sure what console.log statements are but I will try to figure that out thanks for feedback.

Comment: These do not look defined given the code provided: `btRoll`, `tbBet`, `retnum()`, `delay`, `roll3()`, `MultLoss`, `DLoss`...Are these objects anything we want? If so, I will make them all 0.

Comment: Micheal, I appreciate the feedback! I know its not defined because i took part of the code out of the entire script to show an example. my main goal is to have a continuous loop without using "loops" I want to send the script back up. Or if its said like this: :I want to call a function But am I calling these functions correctly? Also Is it better if I share the entire script?

Comment: @pabrams, and zer00ne, yes this is just a portion of the entire script should I post the whole thing to have more context?

Comment: @Mike "read" = "execute". "reading spot" = "point of execution". "I want the code to be read from the beginning, I don't want it to continue from its current reading spot" = "I want the execution to flow back to the roll function, not continue down its current path." Just throwing the lingo out there in case you want to use it. We all knew what you meant. :)

Comment: @cwharris Thanks alot! haha Clearly you can see how new I am. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function ends, it returns to where the function was called. If you want the code in your `decision` function to happen after every `roll` you need to explicitly call `decision()`

```
function roll() {
    if (Dloss === false) {
        if (loop === true) {
            tbBet.value = start;
            btRoll.click();
            refreshIntervalId = setInterval(roll2, delay);
        }
    }
    if (Dloss === true) {
        if (loop === true) {
            tbBet.value = start;
            btRoll.click();
            refreshIntervalId = setInterval(decision, delay);
        }
    }
    decision() // <--- Like so
}
function decision() {
    if (Dloss === true) {
        var thestring = document.getElementById('roll').value;
        var thenumber = retnum(thestring);
        if (thenumber < rollUnder) {
            start = (start * remain).toFixed(2);
        }
        if (thenumber > rollUnder) {
            start = (start * MultLoss).toFixed(2);
            if (start > maxBetValue) {
                loop = false;
            }
            btRoll.click();
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            roll();
        }
        btRoll.click();
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        roll3();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks brett, I will quickly try this out I think what happened was I had confused intervals with calling functions, my mistake. This makes more sense. I will try it out. Also is there a difference between calling functions like you showed and the way i did it with a semi colon after? "decision()" or "decision();"

Comment: Javascript will automatically insert semicolons for you. This can, however, cause issues if you're not careful. So when in doubt, use a semicolon, that was an oversight on my end.

Comment: Commaneur, Thanks so much. That was exactly the issue I was having! I had for some reason just confused calling a function with something else. I have fixed it and now the script does the job its supposed to! Do I need to close the topic or something? And should I edit my post to be less confusing and less detail to help anyone in future or is it fine?